# TagLib Publisher Tag does not work

Tags: c#, taglib

I have searched in stackoverflow.com for how to get publishr tag using taglib...

I found this:

[Is there an equivalent field to Label/Publisher in taglib-sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361102/is-there-an-equivalent-field-to-label-publisher-in-taglib-sharp)

I tried to make it but when i create a taglib file it does not appear ...
this is my code:

```
TagLib.File tg = TagLib.File.Create("");
tg.Tag.publisher
```

it gives me error when I type .publisher

this is the changes where i have made in the taglib files:

TagLib/Id3v2/FrameTypes.cs:

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyByteVector TPUB = "TPUB";
```

TagLib/Id3v2/Tag.cs:
under TagLib.Tag region:

```
public string Publisher
    {
        get { return GetTextAsString(FrameType.TPUB); }
        set { SetTextFrame(FrameType.TPUB, value); }
    }
```

please some help!!!

Comment: Is it a typo that you wrote tg.Tag.publisher where pulisher is lowercase but your property is capitalized ?

Comment: i write it because I can't find it in the menu

Comment: Did you compile TagLib# after you did the changes ?

Comment: nop I added the folder src that contains all the .cs files and i included it to the project

Comment: Compile it and check again

Comment: and how to compile it if It's included to the project

Comment: Why not just using the taglib project file, do your modification, compile it and the use it in your project ?

Comment: Sources [https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/) -> Download zip -> unzip content -> you get the project file

Comment: Error generating Win32 resource: Error reading icon 'c:\Users\Yaser\Desktop\taglib-sharp-master\taglib-sharp-master\src' -- Access is denied.

Comment: it does not work... I compiled the project after added all the code but I still not find Publisher tag

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the following code to the TagLib/Tag.cs file:

```
public virtual string Publisher
{
    get { return null; }
    set { }
}
```